# simulate geographic distance between servers

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, proxy, traffic, traffic-shaping

I want to simulate geographic distance, so I need to add delay to each receive/transfer package.
I read that squid could work, however, playing with its configuration haven't given me the right results.

If I'm pinging from my own PC to squid server I'm getting ~0.5 time, it's okay (would prefer ~1 time)
If I'm pinging between servers it's only ~0.255 time

I would be glad to find the optimal solution for bad traffic.

---

Squid: Version 3.5.12
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: VmWare pro/VmWare fusion pro let's you do this, but it is paid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tc` to manually add latency to packages.

There are ready-made packages to emulate wide-area networks including delays, dropped packages etc., e.g. [netem](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem).

Comment: thank you! I'll run tests with it and update